# Function to return boolean when two indexes are present and order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

How to write a function callback that will return a `boolean` when ordered `path` matches anywhere from `source` array

I've tried using `Array.prototype.includes` but didn't work out.

Note

1. The `source` array will always be a 2 dimensions and no greater nesting.
2. Empty values will always an array.

```js
const source = [
  ['source', 'nope'],
  ['source', 'id'],
  ['wow', 'source', 'id'],
  ['source', 'nope', 'id'],
  [],
  ['id', 'source'],
  ['id', 'source', 'id']
];


function cb(arr, path) {
  return true;
}

const ans = source.filter(i => cb(i, ['source', 'id']));

console.log(ans) 
// Correct Answer is:
// [['source', 'id'], ['wow', 'source', 'id'], ['id', 'source', 'id']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this covers all scenarios (likely not if `.` is a valid character in the paths), or even if it's a great solution, but it does yield the answer in your comment. Just converts each path to a `.` separated string and looks for the given path as a `.` separated string also.

```js
const source = [
  ['source', 'nope'],
  ['source', 'id'],
  ['wow', 'source', 'id'],
  ['source', 'nope', 'id'],
  [],
  ['id', 'source'],
  ['id', 'source', 'id']
];


function cb(arr, path) {
  return arr.join('.').includes(path);
}

const ans = source.filter(i => cb(i, ['source', 'id'].join('.')));

console.log(ans) 
// Correct Answer is:
// [['source', 'id'], ['wow', 'source', 'id'], ['id', 'source', 'id']]
```

Comment: Ahh that's clever! This actually will work for my usecase!